# Is the Mandalorian War canonical again?

Tags: star-wars, star-wars-rebels

My understanding of the Disney canon is that everything was purged. This would include all the Old Republic games and comics books associated with them that mentioned the Mandalorian War.

In the episode of *Star Wars: Rebels* "Trials of the Darksaber", however, Kanan gets angry at Sabine for attacking him with Mandalorian tricks and said:

> History lesson: the Jedi won the war with Mandalore.

Is Kanan referring to the Mandalorian War here, and are there any other sources more obviously confirming that the Mandalorian War happened in the new canon?

Comment: It is worth remembering that the Legends continuity is not wholly disowned, just considered more apocrypha than cannon. Also Rebels is doing it's best to re canonise as much as possible.

Comment: I don't see how they could have made this more confusing. Not jus the Mandalorian Wars but what is or isn't cannon.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

### Mandalorian-Jedi conflicts are canon...

This has been true [at least since](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/148331/31051) season 2 of *The Clone Wars* animated show, when Obi-Wan references ancient conflicts:

> **Obi-Wan:** I know these commandos fought in many wars, often against the Jedi.
>
> <sup>*Star Wars: The Clone Wars* Season 2 Episode 12: "The Mandalore Plot"</sup>

And later episodes glimpsed Mandalorian art, depicting ancient Mandalorians battling lightsaber-wielding figures:

[image]

<sup>Image from *Star Wars: The Clone Wars* Season 5 Episode 16: "The Lawless"</sup>

### ... but [the Mandalorian Wars](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Mandalorian_Wars) are not

Unless future canon works reference other elements from those series, no other elements of the *Old Republic* games, novels, or comics are canon. This has been the consistent position of the LucasFilm Story Group ever since the Legends/Canon division was first announced: referencing an element of Legends continuity in a Canon work only canonizes that element, not the entirety of its (expansive) EU history.

So, unless a future Canon work says otherwise, *nothing* about the Mandalorian Wars as seen in past works is canon.